# Can solutions like "Airwatch", "Mobile Iron" be tested in Mobile Emulators?

Tags: mdm

There are several market players available for MDM.
Two of the most prominent players on the market are AirWatch and Mobile Iron.

My question is can solutions like AirWatch and Mobile Iron be tested in Mobile Emulators instead of real devices for their expected behavior? (i.e. correct security implementations)

**Considered Platforms**

- Android
- Windows Phone

Comment: This question isn't very good fit for Stack Overflow. It's not software development problem, but rather QA + usage of 3rd party apps questions. Also, you didn't specified managed platform. Generally speaking, Android Emulator could be used to test security related product, however I wouldn't use iOS Simulator, because it's reasonably different (from security standpoint) from a real device.

Comment: @VictorRonin wasn't sure where to put it as practically speaking this wouldn't quite be a QA question either.

And I really should have given the platforms (gonna edit it)>
Not consdiering iOS at all.

Primary focus on Android and if possible then in Windows Phone

Comment: Got it. I have no idea about Windows Phone. However, rule of thumb is if it's emulator (which emulate processor and have full image of OS) you can test most of your security stuff on it. If it's simulator (recompiled OS to run directly on some other hardware), quite often they remove some security mechanisms.

Comment: @VictorRonin I'll be using "Emulator" what I am worried about is how the "push settings" will work under the emulator.

As the primary objective will be to see if the configuration pushes from the Web portal will work perfectly in the emulator or not\

Comment: Simple answer: Any of the above MDM service doesn't work on Emulators. They can be tested only on real devices.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cant work with these MDM on the emulator. MDM works with various parameters like UUID (Unique ID), deviceToken, iOS certificate signing, etc.. These parameters can't be provided my emulators.

Comment: To add to this answer, if you or your company are ponying up enough cash to buy/license an MDM solution you should also budget paying for a samples of your device landscape for testing (iOS, Android, etc).